# Is Stackoverflow not working properly

Tags: support

I can't see the Web page displaying properly. I have been trying to access it since morning but unable to do so because it's not displaying the web page properly. Yes, Meta Stackoverflow is working fine. I'm not even able to login into Stackoverflow.

Browser I'm using: Firefox Latest version on Windows 7 Professional

Attaching the Image of stackoverflow :[image]

Comment: And Meta-SO is working perfectly?

Comment: @hjpotter92 I think MSO runs on a different circuit, so to speak - I've seen an answer where a staff member alludes to MSO not using the CDN for resources and stuff.

Comment: If your internet is having issues it can drop packets - specifically the ones where your browser was fetching the css for the site. I have seen this occur during times of my internet running poorly.

Comment: Firefox Version : 21.0 . Does this makes sense?

Comment: @TravisJ +1 this happens often to me, the CSS just fails to load and you're left with a raw page. Usually comes from poorly routed CDN's, but it also happens with bad internet (especially over wifi).

Comment: Hmm, But I'm not using Wifi at my work place. Perhaps a bad connection is the only main cause

Comment: @Tan Firefox tends to upgrade frequently, but I believe Firefox us up to v24 at the moment.  V21 is at least 3 months old.  You might want to check that you are indeed up to date.  Typical SO only supports the current and previous 2 versions.  You might be out of date. (not saying this is the problem, just that the browser might no longer be officially supported)

Comment: Use the dev tools of your choice (e.g. Firebug in FF) and look at network activity when the page is loaded. Chances are, one or more resources is not making it to your machine. This can be for a variety of reasons, nearly all of which are out of SO's control.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens from time to time. Usually, several refreshes will clear it.

If that doesn't work, clear your cache and try again.

Works for me.

Comment: do CTRL + F5 to refresh

Answer (score 2):

It may not be the problem with Meta Stack Overflow, it is just a basic problem with your internet or browser while trying yo connect with Meta Stack Overflow and this is the reason why as Emrakul's suggestion (Usually, several refreshes will clear it. If that doesn't work, clear your cache and try again.) work out.

When the webpage is refreshed the request is send once again and it rectifies the problem.